# Codesys 3, Is there any way to stop CANopen_Manager sending NMT Reset node command on enable?

Tags: can-bus, codesys, canopen, iec61131-3

I've noticed that when enabling the 3S CANopen_manager device (as declared in the device tree, _3SCOS.CANOpenManager_Diag), by `CANopen_Manager.Enable := TRUE;` (I'm not talking about NMT start) the PLC automatically sends NMT Reset command to children/slaves. Obviously this happens even if I use a very basic configuration with just the device Enabled at start and no autostart.

This is a problem because I'm planning to have a dynamic/multi-master, so at all times there will be an active CANopen_Manager in the system, and an inactive CANopen_Manager. However when the inactive CANopen_Manager becomes active (pre-operational), it sends an NMT reset for the slave, an IO unit,  that requests its programming, and will lose its IO status for the duration of the SDO transmission.

Is there any way around this?

I tried starting the device with the CANopen_Manager enabled and autostart (the default configuration), but also starting it without autostart and with the manager disabled.

The only way I've managed to stop the SDO's is checking "no initialization" on my slave, but then the slave doesn't start with NMT commands.

I can't add new tags so I'll name-drop Codesys 3 and CiA 405 in here.

Comment: This sounds so very product-specific that you are probably best off contacting the PLC support. Or perhaps try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, it's a better place to ask questions about PLC.